# How does lexical scope work here when setTimeout is involved?

Tags: javascript

consider the following code:

```
function foo (){

 var count = 40;
 setTimeout(function bar(){
   console.log(count)
 })
 count = 50;
}

foo();
```

This correctly prints `50` which is fine. However, if I just pass `count` as a parameter to function `bar`, it prints `undefined`. Why does it not take the value from its lexical scope?

```
function foo (){

 var count = 40;
 setTimeout(function bar(count){
   console.log(count)
 })
 count = 50;
}

foo(); //Prints undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, your function has a [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) to count, and since the `setTimeout` callback runs after the assignment, you see the value 50.

In the second case, your function accepts a argument called count. The argument is "stronger" than the outer variable (since its in the local scope of the function) and since you are not passing it as an argument on the function call, it's value is `undefined`.

Comment: Ah, Got it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

count is defined in the functional scope of foo function as setTimeOut execute after some time, it comes out of the foo functional scope where count was declared that's why it give undefined